# Unable to scroll using touchpad in Steam

Tags: windows-8, touchpad, dell-inspiron

I had this problem with my previous laptop and fixed it using [this](http://blog.alexou.net/2010/07/scrolling-in-gtk-apps-with-synaptics-driver/) guide. I recently bought a Dell Inspiron which uses Dell Touchpad drivers. I've searched the registry and can't see anything to do with Synaptics and the same for my program files. This leads me to believe they're no longer involved.

Does anybody have any idea which registry key I need to edit?

Comment: Can you refer the concrete laptop model? Do you still have the problem you had in your previous laptop?

Comment: It's a Dell Inspiron 15. The problem is the same as what occurred in my previous laptop, though I can't fix it the same way.

If it helps the new touchpad drivers seem to be made by Elan, though I can't find anything similar in RegEdit.

Comment: The guide states that he used Process Monitor and Spy++ to figure out what was wrong. First - different drivers, we can assume there to be different problems. Second, have you tried to use the "standard" Windows drivers for the touchpad and see if it solves? Third, an approach similar to the one described in that guide can be done... if you have a meager understanding of what the tools do.